# Length of words from getchar()

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program in C to print the length of words entered through getchar(). Here's the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int main()
{
int c, chars, state, i;
int nlength[20];

state = OUT;
chars = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i){
   nlength[i] = 0;
}


while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
     if (c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n'){
        state = IN;
        ++chars;
     }

     else if (state == OUT){
             ++nlength[chars];
             chars = 0;
     }
}
if (c == EOF){
  ++nlength[chars];
}  

printf("\nLength of words = ");

for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i){
   printf(" %d", nlength[i]);
}

printf("\n");
}
```

It's supposed to output, for an example of an input of "aaa aaa", : 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 ... .
However, it outputs something like 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0... . Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: This is the perfect opportunity to use a debugger to trace the code and see what is really going on. Do it, it's fun! :-)

Comment: @someuser what do you mean

Comment: At first, why do you need state variable if you don't use it? Secondly, you aren't incrementing a length of the current word  but a word index in the array.

Comment: @someuser Thanks for the reply, I'm a complete noob to programming.

Comment: Something like that: http://pastebin.com/N5x4rS1x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `state` is never changed to `OUT`, so the following lines:

```
 else if (state == OUT){
         ++nlength[chars];
         chars = 0;
 }
```

are never executed.

There are also several places which look suspicious. E.g. you never check for array boundaries. Also you do not need a `state` variable, you can just check if `chars > 0`.

Here is your code with some modifications:

```
#include <stdio.h>
// we can use isspace function from ctype.h
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_LEN 20

int main() {
  int c;
  int chars = 0;
  // this way we don't have to zero the array explicitly
  int nlength[MAX_LEN] = {0};

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (!isspace(c))
      ++chars;
    else {
      // if chars == 0 we increment nlength[0]
      // which is not used anyway
      if (chars < MAX_LEN)
        ++nlength[chars];
      chars = 0;
    }
  }

  // if chars == 0 we increment nlength[0]
  if (chars < MAX_LEN)
    ++nlength[chars];

  // set 0-length words element to zero
  nlength[0] = 0;

  printf("\nLength of words = ");

  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LEN; ++i) {
    printf(" %d", nlength[i]);
  }

  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: @lakov Davydov Thank you so much for that, it really cleared things up.